# Unable to upload a file with Selenium - Ruby

Tags: ruby, wordpress, selenium, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload a file using a bot written in Ruby. It failed but I think my synthax to be good. I suppose that the recent upgrade of Firefox unabled me to do the job. Have you got an idea please ?

I used these resources to do my code :

https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/best-practices-tips-selenium-file-upload

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/1-upload-a-file

I got the last version of selenium here :

https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver/versions/2.53.0?locale=fr

I got the last version of geckodriver here :

https://rubygems.org/gems/geckodriver-helper/versions/0.0.3

But it didn't work : WebDriverError@chrome://marionnette/content/error.js:235:5 File not found

I am using wordpress in local mode with local by flywheel.
Firefox Quantum 57.0 64bits

Here is my little code :

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec/expectations'
include RSpec::Matchers

def setup
  @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
end

def teardown
  @driver.quit
end

def run
  setup
  yield
  teardown
end

run do
  @driver.get "http://mywebsite.dev/wp-admin/profile.php"
  inputlogin = @driver.find_element :id => "user_login"
  inputpwd = @driver.find_element :id => "user_pass"

  inputlogin.send_keys "mylogin"
  inputpwd.send_keys "mypwd"
  @driver.find_element(:id, "wp-submit").click

  @driver.get "http://mywebsite.dev"
  element = @driver.find_element(:id, 'uploadInput1')
  element.send_keys "C:\\path\\image.jpg"

  # @driver.find_element(id: 'btn-submit').click

  puts "Successful on #{@driver.title}"
end
```

As it didn't work, I was looking for an other way to upload my file so I tried using AutoIT but I failed... Here is an example.

http://www.maisasolutions.com/blog/How-to-upload-images-using-selenium-webdriver-with-ruby

Moreover, this solution is very heavy (downloads, installations, non reproductability etc.) and don't seems to be proper code.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Find a file field on the page and attach a file given its path.
The file field can be found via its name, id or label text.

```
page.attach_file(locator, '/path/to/file.png')
```

Here, locator will be`CSS` id or class of file  upload path.